# C++ Protobuf Error google::protobuf::internal::kEmptyString Error

Tags: c++, c++11, protocol-buffers

I am facing an issue while linking the protobuf library.

> /tmp/ccKgczB9.o:TickData.pb.cc:(.text+0x444): undefined reference to
>   `google::protobuf::internal::kEmptyString'
>   /tmp/ccKgczB9.o:TickData.pb.cc:(.text+0x4a9): undefined reference to`
>   google::protobuf::internal::kEmptyString'
>   /tmp/ccKgczB9.o:TickData.pb.cc:(.text+0x4c4): undefined reference to
>   `google::protobuf::internal::kEmptyString'
>   /tmp/ccKgczB9.o:TickData.pb.cc:(.text+0x4de): undefined reference to`
>   google::protobuf::internal::kEmptyString'
>   /tmp/ccKgczB9.o:TickData.pb.cc:(.text+0x502): undefined reference to
>   `google::protobuf::internal::kEmptyString'
>   /tmp/ccKgczB9.o:TickData.pb.cc:(.text+0x53c): more undefined
>   references to`google::protobuf::internal::kEmptyString' follow
>   /tmp/ccKgczB9.o:TickData.pb.cc:(.text$_ZN6google8protobuf8internal10WireFormat16VerifyUTF8StringEPKciNS2_9OperationE[__ZN6google8protobuf8internal10WireFormat16VerifyUTF8StringEPKciNS2_9OperationE]+0x1b):
>   undefined reference to
>   `google::protobuf::internal::WireFormat::VerifyUTF8StringFallback(char
>   const*, int, google::protobuf::internal::WireFormat::Operation)'
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Language Used: C++
Protobuf Version: 2.6.1

I have already tried stuff on below links but it doesnt work out:

[Can't compile example from google protocol buffers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404027/cant-compile-example-from-google-protocol-buffers)

and

[Undefined reference to google::protobuf::internal::empty_string_[abi:cxx11]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30124264/undefined-reference-to-googleprotobufinternalempty-string-abicxx11)

I am new to C++. I have also tried compiling the protobuf using -std=c++11 but still the same error.

Any pointers will be helpful.

Comment: Please show the compiler command-line you used. (My guess is that it is missing the `-lprotobuf` flag.)

Comment: g++ -g -L"/cygdrive/d/Softwares/protobuf-2.6.1/src/.libs" ../proto/TickData.pb.cc main.cpp -std=c++11 -lprotobuf

Answer (score 0):

I did figure out a way out.

I need to first use the -c option for g++ and generate the .o files. Then again separately will have to use the -o option to generate the executable.

As shown below:

g++ -c -L/cygdrive/d/Workspace/CPP/Practice/.libs/ ../proto/TickData.pb.cc main.cpp -std=c++11 -lprotobuf

g++ -g -Wall TickData.pb.o main.o -o MarketData.o -std=c++11 -lprotobuf